# How can the id automaticly inserted in python mysql?

Tags: python, mysql

I want to insert data into my database, but how can the id auto increment in python?

In PHP, we only do this by using DEFAULT like this query and data inserted:

```
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO setting VALUE(DEFAULT,'$name','$address')");
```

How can i do it in PYTHON MYSQL?

```
def insertSetting(name,address):
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', database='myDB', user='root', password='')
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        query = """INSERT INTO setting (id_setting, name, address) VALUES (DEFAULT, %s, %s) """
        records =(name,address)
        cursor.executemany(query,records)
        connection.commit()
        print("Inserted successfully")

    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print("Failed to insert into MySQL table {}".format(error))

    finally:
        if (connection.is_connected()):
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            print("MySQL connection is closed")

insertSetting(name,address)
```

I got error :

> Failed to insert into MySQL table Failed processing format-parameters;
>   'int' object is not iterable

i expect the result : 
The id auto increment in database

Comment: You don’t want `executemany`! You’re just inserting one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove your column `id_settings` during insert since its `auto increment`.

```
 query = """INSERT INTO setting (name, address) VALUES (%s, %s) """
```